# SOA and OSB Tier is missing in jdeveloper 12c Can some one help me adding those?

Tags: installation, soa, jdeveloper, osb

As mentioned Jdev12C installation should bring osb and soa tire by default to create a new project but even after multiple installs and extensions updates. I was not able to get them in my jdev.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the 12c release you need to get the SOA Quick Start installation that has a JDeveloper with the extensions built in:
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/lcm/SOAQS/GUID-B0669721-B863-4515-BD60-086FDA67A559.htm#SOAQS202

Answer (score 1):

You have to download & install Oracle Soa Suite from [Soa Extensions](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/soasuite/downloads.html) in order to get a complete package with Soa Extensions. Oracle was providing separate extensions to download and include in its previous versions (i.e 11) for J Developer but now it comes in complete packages.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same  issue. Later I realized that my JAVA_HOME - "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80**" contains space.

Oracle installation guide at "https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/SOAQS/integrated.htm#BEIJGFHE" says that "***The installation path must not contain any spaces***".

So I reinstalled jdeveloper following below steps and it worked:

1. Deinstalled jdeveloper by launching the script-
   "C:\Oracle\Middleware\product\Oracle_Home\oui\bin\deinstall.cmd"
2. Removed left over directories-    "C:\Oracle\Middleware"
   "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.3.0.41.140521.1008"
   "C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\12.1.3.0.0"
3. Created a symbolic link "C:\Program_Files" to the directory
   "C:\Program Files".    You can also install JDK to a different path
   which doesn't contain any spaces.
4. Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to
   "C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80".
5. Set PATH=C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;%PATH%
6. Launched the installer from admin command prompt:    java -jar
   fmw_12.1.3.0.0_soa_quickstart.jar