# In jdeveloper12.1.3 SOA and OSB options to create application is missing

Tags: jdeveloper, osb

I have installed JDeveloper 12.1.3 and JDK 1.7.In Jdeveloper option to create new OSB or any SOA suit application is not available.I tried 'check in update'but nothing available but its available in Oracle home directory
Please provide some inputs.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the specific JDeveloper version that comes as part of the SOA installation - The quickstart installation has a pre-configured JDeveloper:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/downloads/soa1213qsdownload-2769533.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding.I installed again using the above given link but still couldn't get OSB option in JDeveloper

Comment: I believe the the OSB part was added in the 12.2.1 versions and wasn't there in the 12.1.3 versions - so upgrade to 12.2.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Check here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50902868/5923789) comment about using spaces in JAVA_HOME.
Maybe this is a reason, except using specific installer for JDev dedicated for SOA.